# ember liquid-teather transitions.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am using ember liquid-teather - http://pzuraq.github.io/liquid-tether/#/examples?a=animation-with-context

The code I have used is from the example under 'Animation With Context'.

The modal works, but there is no nice transitions as am getting an error in the console re the transitions.js file.

See my transitions code below:

```
export default function(){
  this.transition(
    target('modal-dialog'),
    this.toValue(({ index: newIndex }, { index: oldIndex }) => newIndex > oldIndex),
    this.use('tether', ['to-left', options]),
    this.reverse('tether', ['to-right', options])
  );

  this.transition(
    target('modal-dialog'),
    this.toValue(({ index }) => index === 1),
    this.use('tether', 'fade', 'fade')
  );

  this.transition(
    target('modal-dialog'),
    this.toValue(({ index }) => !index),
    this.use('tether', 'fade', 'fade')
  );
}
```

The error is: target not defined.

How do I define target?

Thank you in advance! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check here what values are allowed for options.
http://tether.io/
Search under options :).

Answer (score 0):

scratch that! I have solved my own question. I just needed to declare this at the top of the transitions.js file.

```
import { target } from 'liquid-tether';
```

But now the issue I am getting is 'options not define'.  ...Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

`options` not defined refers to the options you are passing to your animation. It is not very clear from the docs but it is expecting an options hash here. For example:

`this.use('tether', ['to-left', {duration: 500}]),`

Check the liquid fire site for all the options available for animations